# Compare an Identifier against every other in the same column (excluding the cell we are checking) and then comparing dates in google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets

I have 3 columns of data I am analyzing.  Basically if the ID is the same, then I want to compare the dates such that overlapping dates are highlighted.  I think it would be most helpful if I could add a 4th column that then indicates there is an overlap and I could then just look at the rows that have overlapping dates instead of manually looking for them myself.

(I tried to copy and paste the columns but the format messed up so here is the google sheet):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FBS-I0dPjv08hYCd42YLg-wYb-67d2YWmvh2GYvmIEc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better and much simpler solution, but here is a formula that does what I believe you are asking:

`=if(A2=A1, "", iferror(join(", ",filter(unique(arrayformula(filter({filter($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A=A2);filter($C$2:$C, $A$2:$A=A2)}, countif({filter($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A=A2);filter($C$2:$C, $A$2:$A=A2)}, "="&{filter($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A=A2);filter($C$2:$C, $A$2:$A=A2)})>1))), unique(arrayformula(filter({filter($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A=A2);filter($C$2:$C, $A$2:$A=A2)}, countif({filter($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A=A2);filter($C$2:$C, $A$2:$A=A2)}, "="&{filter($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A=A2);filter($C$2:$C, $A$2:$A=A2)})>1)))<>"")),"No repeats"))`

*Please note that this formula **does** need to be copied down the column*

Here is an example of the output, tested in a copy of your sheet:
[image: ex]

Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Hello Kaitlynmm569, thank you so much for putting this together!  I am hoping you could help me to understand what a blank cell means in this instance and also when it doesn't return "no repeats" and instead returns two dates separated by a comma, what does that mean?

For example the screenshot you showed seems to show for id 5449 that there would be an overlap, but by manually scanning the data, I am not seeing that.

Comment: @MichaelA A blank cell is simply there as to not repeat too many things. If there are several of the same id number right after each other, it will only populate the duplicates in the first entry in that group (ie another matching id further down the list would still populate the duplicates as well). Two dates separated by a comma show that there are two overlapping date entries. As for id 5449, there is an entry in row `12741` with those overlapping dates. If you search the sheet for that id number you will find it.